# 404 error when calling cognos report in bluemix application

Tags: ibm-cloud, cognos

I created an app on Bluemix and successfully created a cognos report with sample data using the Embeddable Reporting app. I have saved the report as well. And now I want to display the output of the report on the sample app page. I updated the index.html of my application to invoke the following code

```
var urlRoot = "/ba/cre/";   
var report = new XMLHttpRequest();
var reportID = "ff4012c7689d60845d7f1187cb2133c2";
var reportUrl = urlRoot + 'report/' + reportID + "/run.json";
report.open("GET", reportUrl, true); 
report.send();
```

For this, I get a `404 Not Found` error. From all the sample code online, I know there are 2 formats phtml and json. I presume phtml is for Visualization. Anyway, I tried that as well. Same error. 
Is the constructed URL correct? Is there some direct Cognos report URL that I can try and check if the report is accessible. I know that was possible with the full Cognos version. In this bluemix version, what is the direct Cognos report URL that can be used?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are looking at an old version of the documentation. The API was updated significantly earlier this year.

Please take a look at the new docs here: https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/#services/EmbeddableReporting/index.html#gettingstartedtemplate

Includes a sample using the new API, and the full REST API documentation.

Comment: Thank you. The sample in this doc works well. I assumed the direct URL way would work too like the full version of Cognos.